# Application Insights: requests get sampled despite no ingestion sampling and regardless of what's configured in ApplicationInsights.config

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am working on an ASP.Net (not Core) WebAPI project. For this, I want to be able to do performance testing by capturing telemetry for requests and seeing how much time each request type takes.

When analyzing results I noticed that the number of requests logged in Application Insights is only a fraction of the number of requests of the WebAPI, just about 1/10 or even less. I want to capture all requests so that I have a more decent sample size for my performance analysis, but I am at a loss about what is causing this sampling.

I consulted this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling

- I have looked at the ingestion sampling rate in Azure. This is set to 100%.
- I have tried setting a fixed sampling rate in ApplicationInsights.config.
- I have tried setting adaptive sampling to 1000 per second (way more than the number of requests that we make) and sampling between 90% and 100%.
- I have tried not defining any telemetry processors in ApplicationInsights.config at all.
- I checked our C# code for any occurrences of "sampling" to see if any sampling had been defined in code: no results.

I have seen the exact same behavior on both a server on which we installed our application and when running the application from Visual Studio on my development machine. Both installations send telemetry to different Application Insights instances, each of which are on a different Azure account.

I consulted this documentation from Microsoft to check if sampling is in place: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#how-do-i-know-whether-sampling-is-in-operation

```
let startDateTime = todatetime("2019-03-25 14:00+1:00");
let endDateTime = todatetime("2019-03-25 14:15+1:00");
requests
| where timestamp between(startDateTime..endDateTime)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType
```

This yields percentages between 80% and 100%. However:

```
let startDateTime = todatetime("2019-03-25 14:00+1:00");
let endDateTime = todatetime("2019-03-25 14:15+1:00");
requests
| where timestamp between(startDateTime..endDateTime)
```

This only yields a fraction of the number of records that I would expect based on the actual number of requests handled by our application within this time period. This makes me wonder if Microsoft's method of detecting sampling is even working.

I would expect most of our requests to be logged in Application Insights. I also would expect any applied sampling to respond to changes that I make to settings in ApplicationInsights.config, but settings therein seem to be ignored. I'm at a loss why.

Edit: added the contents of ApplicationInsights.config. This is mostly just the boiler plate stuff generated by Visual Studio:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
<InstrumentationKey>censored</InstrumentationKey>
  <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
  <TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>500</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
    </Add>
  </TelemetryProcessors>

<TelemetryInitializers>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
    <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
  </Add>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>
</TelemetryInitializers>

<TelemetryModules>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
    <Handlers>
      <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Add>
      <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
      <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
      <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
      <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
      <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
      <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
      <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
      <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
    </Handlers>
  </Add>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"></Add>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>
</TelemetryModules>

</ApplicationInsights>
```

Comment: Could you ensure applicationinsights.config is applied correctly? You can do this by setting an incorrect ikey in config and see that there wont be any telemetry flowing. THis is done to ensure that ai.config settings are picked up by the application correcty. (there could be some old ai.config left or something like that) please share your applicationinsights.config as well.

Comment: Seeing that the environments that I used both sent telemetry to the right instance of Application Insights I don't think that this is a problem. I just confirmed this by sabotaging the instrumentation key: when I do this Application Insights stops registering requests.

Comment: Okay. Are you doing a load test and are seeing this behavior? What was the full result of checking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#how-do-i-know-whether-sampling-is-in-operation

Answer (score 0):

Really late to the party, but what was the solution? I currently found a workaround for my logs not being registered but I dislike the approach.

```
 var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
aiOptions.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"];
```

In program.cs, you can disable the adaptive sampling flag of the service I'm injecting.
This works, I've tested some more or less heavy loads but I'd like to keep adaptive sampling turned on, but to make it NOT filter particular logs.